# I'm looking for a code about STDEV.S function of MS Excel

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a code about STDEV.S function of MS Excel.
Note that it is a function that estimates standard deviation based on a sample.

```
STDEV.S
```

Comment: what do you mean by looking for a code? Do you want to do the same calculation without using stdev.s, or do you want to understand how it works?

Comment: @MJ I think you are same talking about that. But especially, I mean it with out stdev.s, How to calculation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equation to calculate standard deviation of a sample is (from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation)):
[image]

So your formula will be:

`=SQRT(1/(COUNT(<range>)-1)*SUMSQ(<range>-AVERAGE(<range>)))`

Note that this should be entered as an array formula (press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER when you finished instead of just ENTER)